# How do I reference a file location in C++?

Tags: c++, windows

I'm trying to reference some images so that this bit of code can work on any PC, not just my own.

```
pictureBox1->ImageLocation = "C:\\Users\\W10\\Desktop\\pacanelematii\\cireasamtii.png";
```

It's a small project in c++, using windows forms in visual studio. Can't get the referencing to work.
From what I understood in should look something like "..Debug\pacanelematii\portocalamatii.png"
or "..pacanelematii\portocalamatii.png", but neither is working. I'm thinking that once the file path is referenced to the .exe, I can easily copy the whole folder of the .exe and send the app to anyone willing to try it out. I copied the "pacanelematii" folder to "Debug"

Comment: `./` is the current directory, `../` is the parent directory.
 `..Debug/` or`..pacanelematii/` is not a valid path.

Answer (score 1):

At the start of your program, you should set the current working directory to the folder containing the executable. With the Win32 API, you would do it like this:

```cpp
wchar_t path[MAX_PATH];
GetModuleFileNameW(NULL, path, MAX_PATH);
PathCchRemoveFileSpec(path, MAX_PATH);
SetCurrentDirectory(path);
```

Then, make sure the image is placed in the directory of the executable, and simply use its relative path.
For example, you could place it into a folder `Images` next to the executable, and use it as `Images/imagename.png`.